# Selecting element with respective to the description text using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to use the following code to find and click where it says OAT (ADS05....) in the included screenshot:

```
oatObj = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(@class, 'treeImg') and contains(., 'OAT ')]") 
oatObj.click()
```

[image]

This is popping up the following error:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

This element is definitely clickable, and other places in the code I'm using a similar XPATH match which do work. Is there something different about this XPATH that anyone can see? Here's a screenshot of the element and inspect pane when clicked:

[image]

Comment: Update the question with the complete error trace log of _`ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable...`_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The innerText does contains the text ***OAT*** but canonically the text *`starts-with`* the text ***OAT***

---

### Solution

To click on the ***clickable*** element ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li/span[contains(@class, 'treeImg') and starts-with(., 'OAT')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks I recognize you from helping me a few weeks ago. I tried this but eventually it just timed out and I got a "TimeoutException: Message:" but then there's no message displayed.

Comment: The text based HTML might help us a bit more.

Comment: Actually this pointed me in the right direction I was able to solve my issue. That XPath pointed to more objects on the page than I was expecting including some that were never shown by default so the click was failing. I referenced the last of the list of returned objects (which is always the one I want) and then it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wait before click on the element

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'YourXpath')))
```

And also you can use `find_elements` if there are more elements with same xpath

You can change you way to click by using Java Script and perform Action

Answer (score 0):

`ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable` error you are getting because the element is not interactable at the point of accessing it. May be various reason, sometimes it is not visible and trying to click, sometimes overlay with other elements, sometimes for viewport.

Please find following solutions.

#1 using `WebDriverWait()`

```
oatObj=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'treeImg') and contains(., 'OAT ')]")))
oatObj.click()
```

#2 using `Actions class`

```
oatObj=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'treeImg') and contains(., 'OAT ')]")))

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(oatObj).click().perform()
```

#3 using `JavaScripts Executor`

```
oatObj=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'treeImg') and contains(., 'OAT ')]")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",oatObj)
```

Please import below libraries:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```